# Power Automate: how to get Element from SOSL Query

Tags: powerbi, power-automate

I'm doing a SOSL Query with Power Automate.

[[image: SOSL Query1]

My answer looks like this:

```
{
  "searchRecords": [
    {
      "attributes": {
        "type": "Account",
        "url": "/url/comes/here"
      },
      "Name": "McDonalds GmbH"
    }
  ]
}
```

How do it get the Company Name as string in Power Automate?